# Displaying image source from MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: python, django, media

I have my media_root path set to

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

with my project structured as so

```
   Project_Name/
     media/
       profiles/
   App_Name
```

when I try to reference the images in my `profiles/` directory, I get 404 no resource found errors.

```
     src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ result.photo }}">
```

This resolves to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/profiles/image1.jpg` cannot be found. Am I missing absolute path, I am using DJango 1.4, I do not have the media root set in my urls.py but I didn't with my `STATIC_URL` definitions and I am able to find my static resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the main path of your project

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
SITE_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT
```

In here, the system call your media folder path where uploaded images store

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In here are your static files where css/js/img/ ... store

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Additional location for staticfiles

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'staticfiles'),
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from project_name import settings
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     .........
     .........
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: Try to explain *why* this is the solution and how this works. As it is now, this is just an answer without an explanation.

Comment: Okay, so with these changes the /media/ directory is now created at the root level and i can see files being added (uploading works). I still receive 404 file not found errors with how i am referencing the files in my template?

Comment: you need to update your url that will connect to your media and static. Finish update my answer...

Comment: not adding the changes you suggested to urls.py but changing how i reference the files in my template from {{ MEDIA_URL }} to {{ STATIC_URL}}, fixed it. Why would that have worked?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer**
[Images from media folder is not displaying django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177208/images-from-media-folder-is-not-displaying-django-template/68325385#68325385)

Comment: please stop spamming your answer everywhere. You can add a comment and link your answer but simply rewriting it everywhere will get you downvoted.

Comment: okay. I am new to stack overflow community. That's why I do not know.