# Images from media folder is not displaying django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, django-settings

I am having images in my media folder and I want to display them but Django is not displaying images other than static folder.
In my setting

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),]
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In my urls.py after url pattern I added this

```
+ static(MEDIA_URL, document_root=MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In my templates

```
<img class="card-img-top" style="" src="{{result.object.thumbnail.url}}" alt=""></a>               
   <p>{{result.object.thumbnail.url}}</p>
```

It is showing the correct path but not showing the image, I am unable to figure out the problem. Thanks

Comment: is `MEDIA` folder placed in correct place in your project? is path valid?

Comment: Sir media folder is placed in BASE_DIR, yes the path is correct!

Comment: check my answer, in case you have `media` forder in the root of your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MEDIA_ROOT` have the path of the root of your project. You must join to it, the direcotry of your `media`.  (**I suppose `media/` is the directory name where you upload all your media**) 
I think you should have your `MEDIA_ROOT` like that.

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Comment: Sorry to say but I already tried this one and after your answer I again tried but it's not working

Comment: go in Django admin, find your model instance, try displaying the image there, and show me the `path` shown in the URL

Comment: url is - /media/products/media/images/RAJASTHAN/SIKAR/332001/panshar8688/new/1632140276/thumbnail/1632140276.jpg

Comment: In admin its showing image url but after clicking on it showing KeyError

Comment: The mistake is clearly shown here, `/media/products/media/images`

Comment: @Pankaj Sharma so what it was? :)

Comment: Media URL should be MEDIA_URL = '/'

Comment: Not at all. Depending on how you set `upload_to` in your field... I think you've added the prefix `media/` in your `Field: upload_to`. you should not

Answer (score 0):

**MEDIA_ROOT** have root path of your project. MEDIA_URL must be correct. Check following
**setting.py** of your project

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py** of project

```
 urlpatterns = [
                  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  # url('', include('app1.urls')),
                  url('home/', myapp_views.index)
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
             document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I was facing same error from the last 5 days , follow django documentation, many tutorials but nothing work for me but finally I found the solution

I am showing the index.html on home means I have not given any endpoint in url of my app and project url file

**app/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('', 'views.index', name='index page'),
]
```

**project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
                  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  # url('', include('app1.urls')),
                  url('', myapp_views.index)
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Rest of code remains the same** and I changed the following in both files

**app/urls.py**

```
    url('home/', 'views.index', name='index page'),
```

**project/urls.py**

```
 url('home/', myapp_views.index)
```

That's work for me. Accept the answer if also work for you

Answer (score 0):

This is a chunk of my HTTP logs from django v3.2 running wagtail. Looks as though django is **trying** to tell me where the missing media is but not able to. Because this is a thicket page with gallery sub-images of "featured pages" the view source in my browser doesn't reveal the image file attempt, but I am assuming it is the same issue as OP's with misconfigured MEDIA_ROOT. Strangely, not seeing any errors in the page's linked images when I bring the child page up in wagtail admin. Anyone have an idea why the missing image won't bubble up to the HTTP logs, or what causes the "media/not-found" substitution for the "real" item causing the 404?

[25/Aug/2021 20:28:53] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/images/bg-dark-diag.svg HTTP/1.0" 200 700

Not Found: /media/not-found
[25/Aug/2021 20:29:18] "**GET /media/not-found** HTTP/1.0" 404 3252

Not Found: /media/not-found
[25/Aug/2021 20:29:18] "GET /media/not-found HTTP/1.0" 404 3252

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.